# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doctor.categories' doesn't exist in Laravel 5.4

Tags: insert, laravel-5.4

I am facing a problem in data insert. When I insert a data then get this error message. Anyone help me how I solve this get error?

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'doctor.categories' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `categories` where `name` = Web Development)

**My Route:**

```
Route::resource('home/blog_categories', 'BlogCategoriesController');
```

**My Model: Model Name: BlogCategoriesModel**

```
class BlogCategoriesModel extends Model
{
    protected $table      = 'blog_categories';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $fillable   = ['name'];
}
```

**Controller: Controller Name: BlogCategoriesController**

```
public function store(StoreBlogCategoryRequest $request)
{
    $category = new BlogCategoriesModel;
    $category->name = $request->name;
    $category->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'Data has been save success');
    return redirect()->route('blog_categories.index');
}
```

I use request for validation. Here is my validation code
**StoreBlogCategoryRequest:**

```
public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:50'
        ];
    }
```

And Finally here is my HTML code
**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="br-section-wrapper">
      <h6 class="tx-gray-800 tx-uppercase tx-bold tx-14 mg-b-10">Create New Category</h6>
      {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'blog_categories.store', 'data-parsley-validate' => '')) !!}
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group margin-top15">
              <label for="name">Category Name: <span class="tx-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group margin-top15">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info tx-11 pd-y-12 tx-uppercase tx-spacing-2">Create Categories</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

Please help me. Thanks in Advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are explicitly telling the unique rule to check the `categories` table.

```
'name' => 'required|unique:categories|max:50'
```

Comment: Yaa, It was a great mistake...Thanks bro